# Cut loop OFF-CENTER

Tags: modeling

I have hard time **sliding the cut loop precisely using the vertex snap tool**, on a four-sided object which, in plan view, one side is slanted or non-orthogonal. When I snap to the desired vertex (which I use it as a reference point for the desired position), the cut loop is not aligned with the vertex on the horizontal axis.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Works just fine on my end. But the loopcut needs to be perfectly straight for this to work.

Comment: The loop cut is perfectly straight and it doesn't work for me, as you can see in the screenshot:(

Comment: Okay, after some testing it doesn't work reliably all the time :). An alternative is to use Knife or Knife project to place an edge precisely.

Comment: Any fix for this issue?

Comment: No idea. It seems more like a bug. It only snaps correctly right after I add the loopcut.